# Peculiar behavior of *java loops* in *leet code*

Tags: java, arrays

I have been solving this problem called [63. Unique Paths II](https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-paths-ii/) on `LeetCode.com`. I need some pre filling and for that I needed to run this loop.

```
for (int row = 1; row < grid[0].length; row++) {
   if (grid[row][0] == 1) {
      grid[row][0] = 0;
      break;
   }
   grid[row][0] = 1;
}
```

It is pretty clear that if the `index`, which in this case the `row` iterator, becomes equal the the length of the `array` under consideration then it should exit the loop. But in my case it is giving this error

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for
> length 1   at line 18, Solution.uniquePathsWithObstacles   at line 54,
> **DriverSolution**.**helper**   at line 84, **Driver**.main

which is a kind of peculiar. Am I missing out something or it is peculiar?

Here is my complete code, my approach shouldn't the part of discussion, because if there is an problem I would like to find out by myself. For now I would  like to hear about the peculiar behavior I have mentioned above.

```
class Solution {
    public int uniquePathsWithObstacles(int[][] grid) {

        if(grid[0][0] == 1 || grid[grid.length - 1][grid[0].length - 1] == 0){
            return 0;
        }

        for(int col = 1; col < grid.length; col ++){
            if(grid[0][col] == 1){
                grid[0][col] = 0;
                break;
            }
            grid[0][col] = 1;
        }


        for(int row = 1; row < grid[0].length; row ++){
            if(grid[row][0] == 1){
                grid[row][0] = 0;
                break;
            }
            grid[row][0] = 1;
        }

        for(int i = 1; i < grid.length; i ++){
            for(int j = 1; j < grid[i].length; j ++){
                grid[i][j] = grid[i][j] != 1 ? grid[i - 1][j] + grid[i][j - 1] : 0;
            }
        }
        return grid[grid.length - 1][grid[0].length - 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: While line is line 54?

Comment: I removed that wile, it was a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You're making a mistake

- if you iterating like `grid[row][i]` the condition should be `row<grid.length`.
- if you iterating like `grid[i][row]` the condition should be `row < grid[i].length` (`row < grid[i].length` acceptable if all rows are same length)

---

So your loops should be

```
for (int col = 1; col < grid[0].length; col++) {
    if (grid[0][col] == 1) {
        grid[0][col] = 0;
        break;
    }
    grid[0][col] = 1;
}

for (int row = 1; row < grid.length; row++) {
    if (grid[row][0] == 1) {
        grid[row][0] = 0;
        break;
    }
    grid[row][0] = 1;
}
```